# The usage of global static pointer with multiple initialize?

Tags: c++, static, global-variables

I declared a global static pointer out of main function in main.cpp file. Do I need to initialize it in each cpp file it is used?

```
// main.cpp
...
static int *levels;
...
int main()
...
```

Then, if I have to initialize it in some other files rather than main.cpp, then what is the usage of global static variable? I can declare separate pointers in each cpp file.

Comment: You need to initalze it only **once**!

Comment: A static variable is by definition not global.  It only exists in the file that it is declared in.  You cannot access it in any file other than main.cpp.

Comment: Also note, that `static` refers to c-syntax here, and makes levels exclusively visible inside `main.cpp`.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: Then it's not the way that I make a static variable that initialize in other cpp file?

Comment: If using such pattern at all, create a singleton class to wrap it!

Comment: Good offer. Thank you. I have learned some good points now.

Comment: @JalalJaberi I put it into an answer to elaborate a bit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would not generally advise to use singleton classes is good style, but here's what I would do:

`MySingleton.hpp:`

---

```
class MySingleton {
public:
    static MySingleton& instance() {
        static MySingleton theInstance;
        return theInstance;
    }
    std::vector<int>& levels() { return levels_; }

private:
    MySingleton() {
    }
    std::vector<int> levels_;
};
```

To use the above elsewhere:

```
#include "MySingleton.hpp"

// ...
MySingleton::instance().levels().resize(10); // Creates 10 ints initialized to 0
```

To shorten the access you could even wrap the whole thing in its own namespace and provide free functions there:

```
namespace MySpace {
    class MySingleton {
        // Blah, blah
    };

    std::vector& levels() {
        return MySingleton::instance().levels();
    }
}
```

and use it

```
MySpace::levels().resize(10);
```

Comment: Many overhead for only one pointer! But I'm thinking about it yet.

Comment: @JalalJaberi Not really on the long term (consider e.g. various appliication configuration parameters). Otherwise i mentioned it's not best style. Consider RAII patterns instead of using global variables!

Comment: Yes, but after all, I like your pretty good programming style. This piece of code support my golas more than a simple pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you need it to be initialized.

If there are other static objects that need it:

```
static int * levels = new int[COMPILE_TIME_CONST];
```

is a good start.   Be aware that static variables in a single compilation unit are initialized in the order that they appear in the source.   The order of initialization in relation to statics in other compilation units is a much more complicated issue.

```
Definition: compilation unit is a single cpp file 
and the headers it includes directly or indirectly.
```

Fortunately you cannot access `levels` from any other compilation unit. [edit in response to comments]

If you don't need it until main has started then:

```
int main()
{
    levels = new int[someValueCalculatedInMain];
|
```

works.

Comment: `static int * levels` cannot be accessed from other complaton units, even not if declared using `extern` there!

Comment: I'd like to initialize it in a function in other cpp file (say other.cpp), and then initialize it when I call that function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agreed.  I wonder if the OP was referring to class static variables?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: my problem is now what you said.

Comment: _'in a single compilation unit are initialized in the order that they appear in the source'_ Is this guaranteed by the standard (older also)? AFAIR you can't even rely on this (though it's the usual behavior).

Comment: +1 for clarifying about compilation unit definition.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As I recall the C++03 standard says all zero globals are all initialized first, then any initializers are executed in the order they appear in the compilation unit, but there is no guarantee about the which compilation unit gets initialized first.   If I get some spare time (chuckle) I'll search the standard and quote the relevant passage.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution that will allow access from multiple C++ files:

In a header file:

```
 int * getLevels();
```

In a cpp file:

```
int * getLevels()
{
   static int * levels = new int[calculatedArraySize];
   return levels;
}
```

Warning:  This code is not thread-safe (before C++11 anyway).  If your application uses multiple threads you need some additional code.  This code also leaks the array when the program terminates.  Normally this is not a problem but if it is there are solutions.

Comment: Couldn't you have integrated this additonal information into your other answer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's a completely different approach.  Both answers are valid.  Let the voting (if any) determine which one people find more (or less) useful.

Comment: No, not really. The `static` makes your other answer invalid in fact, as the OP asked for _'Then, if I have to initialize it in some **other files** ...'_

Comment: Isn't it equal to use normal global pointer and using extern to declare it in separate cpp files?

Comment: There is a subtle difference between this an a global value not wrapped in the function. If static initialization from other compilation units references getLevels() then the pointer is guaranteed to be properly initialized.  That is not true for an unwrapped global pointer.   If, on the other hand, the pointer is not referenced until after main is entered, then simply initializing it in main is the simplest solution.