# C++ Incomplete Type Error

Tags: c++, types

(I have read all the threads posted here and google, I was not able to fix from that)

I am having toruble with a incomplete type error when compiling. The way I am designing the project, the game pointer is unavoidable.

```
main.cpp
#include "game.h"
// I actually declare game as a global, and hand itself its pointer (had trouble doing it with "this")
Game game;
Game* gamePtr = &game;
game.init(gamePtr);
game.gamePtr->map->test(); // error here, I also tested the basic test in all other parts of code, always incomplete type.


game.h
#include "map.h"
class Map;

class Game {

    private:
        Map *map;
        Game* gamePtr;

    public:
        void init(Game* ownPtr);
        int getTestInt();
};


game.cpp
#include "game.h"

void Game::init(Game* ownPtr) {
    gamePtr = ownPtr;
    map = new Map(gamePtr); // acts as "parent" to refer back (is needed.)
}

int Game::getTestInt() {
    return 5;    
}


map.h
class Game;

class Map {
    private:
        Game* gamePtr;
    public:
        int test();
};

map.cpp 
#include "map.h"

int Map::test() {
    return gamePtr->getTestInt();
}

// returns that class Game is an incomplete type, and cannot figure out how to fix.
```

Comment: That was only done to hand it its own pointer, I had way too much trouble using "this*" or "this". The way it is now, I get the proper pointer, no problems there. This is actually the new design, I need everything to be able to communicate with everything else (all within a wrapper class)

Comment: Please check how to do proper singleton design, if you really need one. [I've shown a way in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23302354/1413395) and [others tagged singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1413395+singleton).

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to access game.gamePtr on the error line, when you are in Main.cpp, and class game defines its gamePtr as private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over the errors:

1) In `main`, this is an error:

```
    game.gamePtr->map->test();
```

The `gamePtr` and `map` are a `private` members of `Game`, therefore they cannot be accessed.

2) The `Map` is missing a constructor that takes a `Game*` in `Game.cpp`.

```
    map = new Map(gamePtr);
```

---

Here is a full working example that compiles.  You have to provide the functions that are missing bodies, such as `Map(Game*)`.

`game.h`

```
#ifndef GAME_H_INCLUDED
#define GAME_H_INCLUDED

class Map;
class Game {
    private:
        Map *map;
    public:
        Game* gamePtr;
        void init(Game* ownPtr);
        int getTestInt();
    };
#endif
```

`game.cpp`

```
#include "game.h"
#include "map.h"

void Game::init(Game* ownPtr) {
    gamePtr = ownPtr;
    map = new Map(gamePtr); // acts as "parent" to refer back (is needed.)
}

int Game::getTestInt() {
    return 5;    
}
```

`map.h`

```
#ifndef MAP_H_INCLUDED
#define MAP_H_INCLUDED

class Game;
class Map {
    private:
        Game* gamePtr;
    public:
        int test();
        Map(Game*);
};
#endif
```

`map.cpp`

```
#include "game.h"
#include "map.h"

int Map::test() {
    return gamePtr->getTestInt();
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "game.h"
#include "map.h"

int main()
{
    Game game;
    Game* gamePtr = &game;
    game.init(gamePtr);
    game.gamePtr->map->test(); 
}
```

After doing this and creating a project in Visual Studio, I do not get any errors building the application.

Note the usage of `#include guards`, which your original posted code did not have.  I also placed the members that were `private` and moved them to `public` in the `Game` class, so that `main()` can compile successfully.

Comment: +1, I get the feeling that OP's error was caused by a circular include

Comment: Thanks majorly! Everything works as intended, couldn't have done it without your complete example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use forward declaration. Place declaration of Map class before definition of class Game:

```
game.h

class Map; // this is forward declaration of class Map. Now you may have pointers of that type
class Game {

    private:
        Map *map;
        Game* gamePtr;

    public:
        void init(Game* ownPtr);
        int getTestInt();
};
```

Comment: I actually did forward declare in the files, the compiler gives a second error with that, error "forward declare Game."

The problem is I am getting an "incomplete type," the map pointer and initiator works.

Comment: @EvanCarslake do you include game.h into game.cpp?

Comment: Yeah, my bad I left those few things out for consolidation, Ill add.

Answer (score 0):

Every place where you use `Map` and `Game` class by creating instance of it or dereferencing pointer to it either through -> or * you have to make that type "complete". It means that `main.cpp` must include `map.h` and `map.cpp` must include `game.h` directly or indirectly.

Note you forward declare `class Game` to avoid `game.h` to be included by `map.h`, and that is fine and proper, but `map.cpp` must have `game.h` included as you dereference pointer to class `Game` there.